# Transferring Minecraft seeds from WiiU to PS3

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

I have created a Minecraft world on WiiU, and would like to give the seed to someone who uses Playstation 3. When I test run the seed on my WiiU with the x,y,and z coordinates, it shows nothing of what I have created. Is there some way of sharing the seed with all of the created items?

Answer (score 1):

The seed is just used for world generation - it doesn't represent any changes you, the player, have made to the world. If you want to transfer whole worlds you'll need to access the save file in some way, which I'm not sure is possible cross-platform.